# <img src> tag help - learning blazor

Tags: html, asp.net, web, blazor

I am learning Blazor and at the moment I am trying to set an image as the background. I thought I would try display it first as the background-image css didnt work. I have attached a picture of my index.razor page and the img tag i am using is as follows:

```html
<img src="file:///C:/Development/CsharpApplications/Portal/AlbertBartlettPortal/AlbertBartlettPortal/Pages/hero-range-1.jpg" alt="Background Image" />
```

It allows me to ctrl+click the file path and opens the image right away so it can see the image, but it wont display at all when the website is ran.

HELP!

[Page Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ51p.png)

Comment: The image should be placed within your wwwroot folder and a path relative to there should be used.

Comment: @BrianParker I changed the location of the image and changed the path and it still didn't work. I can ctrl+click and the image comes up but it wont appear on the page

Comment: @HenkHolterman thats it, thank you vm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it in wwwroot\images and then used `src="images/aaa.jg"`. No leading `/` OR `~/`